# Create a key comparing two rows in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I have SAS data set which has 2 columns

```
Var1  Var2
A      B
B      C
C      D
D      E
F      G
H      F
```

Can i create a same unique key for above rows. The final output which i want is

```
Var1  Var2  Key
A      B     1
B      C     1
C      D     1
D      E     1
F      G     2
H      F     2
```

Comment: Should key always be 1? Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: What's the logic in your `key` column?

Comment: Please explain what "same unique key" is supposed to mean.

Comment: No, key can we anything.I want to compare one row with other if any column matches with any other column in different rows then i want to assign same value

Comment: What if you add the row (E,F)? Should key be 1 (from D, E), or 2 (from F, G)?

Comment: then it should be 1 and (F,G) should also be 1

Comment: How come it should be 1?

Comment: Do you want SAS code or SQL statement?

Comment: @jarlh - either sql or sas would help

Comment: Please edit the question to add description of the logic for defining the groups.

Answer (score 2):

The general problem of assigning a group identifier based on row-to-row linkages can be very rich and difficult.  However, for the sequential case the solution is not so bad.

**Sample code**

Presume the group identity changes when both variable values are not present in the prior row.

```
data have;input
Var1 $  Var2 $;datalines;
A      B
B      C
C      D
D      E
F      G
H      F
run;

data want;
  set have;
  group_id + ( var1 ne lag(var2) AND var2 ne lag(var1) );
run;
```

**Complex case**

@Vivek Gupta states in comments

> There are random arrangement of rows in the dataset

Consider arbitrary rows p and q with items X and Y. Groups are created by linkages whose criteria is:

```
   p.X = q.X
OR p.X = q.Y
OR p.y = q.x
OR p.y = q.y
```

A hash based solver will populate groups initially from a data scan.  Repeated scans of data with hash lookups migrate items into lower groups (thus enlarging the group) until there is a scan with no migrations.

```
data pairs;
  id + 1;
  input item1 $ item2 $ ;
cards;
A B
C D
D E
B C
H F
X Y
F G
run;

data _null_ ;
  length item $8 group 8;
  retain item '' group .;

  if 0 then set pairs;

  declare hash pairs();
  pairs.defineKey('item1', 'item2');
  pairs.defineDone();

  declare hash map(ordered:'A');
  map.definekey ('item');
  map.definedata ('item', 'group');
  map.definedone();

  _groupId = 0;
  noMappings = 0;

  nPass = 0;

  do until (end);
    set pairs end=end;

    pairs.replace();

    found1 = map.find(key:item1) eq 0; item1g = group;
    found2 = map.find(key:item2) eq 0; item2g = group;

    put item1= item2= found1= found2= item1g= item2=;

    select;
      when (    found1 and not found2) map.add(key:item2,data:item2,data:item1g);
      when (not found1 and     found2) map.add(key:item1,data:item1,data:item2g);
      when (not found1 and not found2) do;
                                       _groupId + 1;
                                       map.add(key:item1,data:item1,data:_groupId);
                                       map.add(key:item2,data:item2,data:_groupId);
                                       end;
      otherwise
      ;
    end;
  end;

  declare hiter data('pairs');

  do iteration = 1 to 1000 until (discrete);

  put iteration=;

    discrete = 1;
    do index = 1 by 1 while (data.next() = 0);

      found1 = map.find(key:item1) eq 0; item1g = group;
      found2 = map.find(key:item2) eq 0; item2g = group;

      put index= item1= item2= item1g= item2g=;

      if (item1g < item2g) then do; map.replace(key:item2,data:item2,data:item1g); discrete=0; end;
      if (item2g < item1g) then do; map.replace(key:item1,data:item1,data:item2g); discrete=0; end;
    end;
  end;

  if discrete then put 'NOTE: discrete groups at' iteration=; else put 'NOTE: Groups not discrete after ' iteration=;

  map.output(dataset:'map');
run;
```

**Complex case #2**

Groups are created by linkages whose criteria is

```
   p.X = q.X
OR p.y = q.y
```

The following example is offsite and too long to post here.

[How to create groups from rows associated by linkages in either of two variables](https://www.devenezia.com/downloads/sas/samples/grouping-pairs-by-either-key.sas)

---

General statement of problem:

```
Given: P = p{i} = (p{i,1),p{i,2}), a set of pairs (key1, key2).

Find: The distinct groups, G = g{x}, of P,
      such that each pair p in a group g has this property:

      key1 matches key1 of any other pair in g.
      -or-
      key2 matches key2 of any other pair in g.
```

---

In short, the example shows

- An iterative way using hashes.
- Two hashes maintain the groupId assigned to each key value.
- Two additional hashes are used to maintain group mapping paths.
- When the data can be passed without causing a mapping, then the groups
  have been fully determined.
- A final pass is done

  - groupIds are assigned to each pair
  - data is output to a table

Comment: i don't have a sequential case. There are random arrangement of rows in the dataset

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can i also compare key1 to key2 or viceversa in the code which you have shared in the link?

Comment: See recent edit, I broke the 'complex cases' into two types based on grouping criteria.

Answer (score 1):

As you have not describe any logic so for your sample output below query will work

```
select Var1, Var2, 1 as [key] 
from t
```

Comment: This example is just a set. So there are multiple sets in my dataset in which F= G G= H then how can i assign a different value for each set